# send data from an api every time a user crosses 5km

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, geodjango

The current location of user might change in a minutes. For example if a user is in location A,
he will get the list of property around 15km from his current location but if he is moving now and
has crossed the 5km from the previous location now show the property around 15km from the new 
location. How can i handle such situation?

Right now this is my code to find nearby property around 15km.

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def nearby_property_finder(request, current_latitude, current_longitude):
    user_location = Point(float(current_longitude), float(current_latitude))
    distance_from_point = {'km': 15}
    properties = Property.gis.filter(location__distance_lte=(user_location,D(**distance_from_point)))
    properties = properties.distance(user_location).order_by('distance')
    if properties.exists():
        paginator = ResultInPagination()
        paginated_properties = paginator.paginate_queryset(properties, request)
        serializer=PropertySerializer(paginated_properties, many=True)
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Wouldnt you have to poll the user continuously in order to update the coordinates??

Comment: Yeah i need to track the user coordinates continuously. I am blank regarding the best way to handle real time property finder based on the current location of user. Do i need to use websocket in client side?

Comment: Hmm. How are you getting the coordinates in the first place?

Comment: I will be using geolocation API for getting the location of users. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

Comment: I guess you could use websocket or AJAX to send for the users location periodically. You have to be able to do that for this to work and both websockets and ajax would work.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I thought i need to handle the nearby property code in background using celery. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I am not sure, it might be a bit of an overkill. But I have not used celery extensively. This seems to be a matter of simple polling though, AJAX and websockets were built for this use case. I hope someone with some celery experience can clarify this though.